# Main method constructor not applied properly

Tags: java

I am having a hard time implementing my main class to work properly. I am getting a compiler errors saying "`constructor inc1 in class inc1 cannot be applied to given types;`" and it says "`required: inc1_dice,inc1_player`". I fairly certain that it has to do with the fact that the constructor in the `inc1` class has "`(inc1_dice dice, inc1_player player)`" but I can't figure out how to adjust my main class to fix the issue.

If anyone knows how to do so please let me know I would greatly appreciate it!

Main class:

```
public class inc1_main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        inc1 inc = new inc1();
        inc.go();
    }
}
```

Part of Play class:

```
public class inc1{
  private inc1_player player;
  private inc1_dice dice;

  public inc1(inc1_dice dice, inc1_player player){
     this.dice = dice;
     this.player = player;
  }
```

Comment: If a method (including a constructor) is declared to take parameters, you have to supply them when you call it.  `new inc1()` is not passing any parameters, so you get a compile error telling you what you need to add (inc1_dice and inc1_player).

Comment: @azurefrog okay so I added inc1_dice, inc1_player to the inc1 inc = new inc1(); in the main and it says cant find symbol

Comment: Well, that's a different question.  (P.S. please don't ask that question until after you've googled the error message and at least read the canonical SO answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared that constructor of class `inc1` needs two arguments to create instance of this class:

`inc1(inc1_dice dice, inc1_player player) {...}`

and you didn't provide your own constructor taking no arguments:

```
inc1() {...}
```

This means that you can't create instance of `inc1` with the use of ***default constructor*** (constructor taking no arguments). The reason is that if you declare your own constructor, you can't create instances of your class with the use of *default constructor*, unless you provide your own constructor taking no arguments.

Summarizing what I've said, you need to first create instances of `inc1_dice` and `inc1_player` the way you declared they should be created) or create instances of these classes "on-the-go":

```
inc1_dice dice = new inc1_dice();
inc1_player player = new inc1_player();
inc1 myObject = new inc1(dice, player);
```

or the second way:

```
inc1 myObject = new inc1(new inc1_dice(), new inc1_player());
```

Another possibilty is to prepare your own constructor in `inc1` class that takes no arguments:

```
public class inc1{
    private inc1_player player;
    private inc1_dice dice;

    public inc1(inc1_dice dice, inc1_player player){
       this.dice = dice;
       this.player = player;
    }

    public inc1() {
        // here are actions you want to perform when constructor
        // taking no arguments is called...
    }
}
```

*By the way, it's good to follow Java naming conventions - they say that you should name classes in Java starting with capital letter (e.g. Inc1, Inc1Dice, etc.)*

Comment: Okay so I got it all solved with no compiler errors now. But when I run the main I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" any idea what that means?

Comment: @DestinyCoots Look at the code of go() method (you didn't include that method in your question and it seems that you need to look for a bug there - it seems that it perform some kind of action on and on and never stop until you're out of memory - but it's impossible to tell what kind of bug is there as we don't see that).

Comment: Yeah it was an infinite while loop. I have all the methods that I need completed I just have to properly organize them in a way to make my go method work. If I can't figure it out I would address kit in a different question but thanks for your help on the main and pointing me towards the issue being the go method!

Comment: @DestinyCoots Glad that I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor in your inc1 class has parameters in it.  Once you've created a constructor with parameters in it, the Java compiler will not automatically generate a default constructor for you.  (That is a constructor that takes no parameter arguments)

So the inc1 constructor you're trying to call, take two parameters.  So in your main class, you'll need to create a inc1_dice and a inc1_player object, set them up, then pass them in to your constructor.

Comment: Alright I got now compiler errors now but when I run I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" any idea what that means?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`inc1 inc = new inc1();`

you need something along the lines

`inc1 inc = new inc1(dice, player);`

where `dice` is instance of `inc1_dice` and `player` is an instance of `inc1_player`. Alternatively, add a default constructor to class `inc1`.

Comment: when I do that (dice, player) it says it cant find the dice and player symbols

Comment: @destinycoots Because you have to instantiate them before this call. Something like `inc1_dice dice = new inc1_dice(); inc1_player player = new inc1_player();` Assuming of course that you wrote classes `inc1_dice` and `inc1_player`.

Comment: Yeah I have the classes for it and I got it figured out. Now though when I run my main I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" any idea what that means?

Comment: @destinycoots It means that your program ran out of memory. It happens when you create a very large array, for example. Check your code carefully, you didn't show us the body of `go()` method nor the classes `inc1_dice` and `inc1_player`.

Comment: I created another question to deal with the issue becausde I  can't figure it out. Feel free to look at all my code there if you want! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602043/go-method-creating-heap-space-issue-in-dice-game

Answer (score 0):

Class names should start with capital letters, it's a Java convention.
So, your classes are *Inc1_main* and *Inc1*. If you follow the standard guidelines (at least most of them) will help anyone that checks your code.

About your question, when you call the constructor you must pass 2 parameters, because you've specified them in your class code. So the code *new inc1()* should be changed to *new Inc1(a, b)* where *a* and *b* are instances of *Inc1_dice* and *Inc1_player*.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, each class has by default a default ctor - one that receives no args.

When you created a ctor that receives args, you can no more expect to call a ctor with no args, until you define one.

Hence, in your main(), you should call

```
    inc1 inc = new inc1(-args-);
```

Or, create a new ctor that receives no args.

Hope that helps...

Comment: it's `constructor`, not `ctor`