# Go method creating heap space issue in dice game

Tags: java

I am working on code where a user rolls 5 customized dice and for each time they roll a 5 or 10 that number gets added to their total score until they reach a total score of 500 and then the game ends. I have all of the methods that I will need to construct my go method but I can't quite figure it out without it causing me to run out of heap space.

My current go method gives me an array of the rolls that the player got but then just says the updated score is 0 no matter what they actually roll. I then clear so that I can re-roll but that requires a loop and when I do that I get the heap space issue. I can't figure out how to create the proper game without so type of heap space issue. Any help on figuring it out would be appreciated!

something possibly like:

```
while (checkIfWinner() != true){
     System.out.println(dice.rollDice());
     dice.addFivesOrTens();
     System.out.println("After that roll your updated score is " + player.getTotalScore());
     dice.rollDice().clear();  
}
```

but this creates a heap space issue

**NOTE:** The go method is in the game class

Dice class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class inc1_dice{
   private int die1;
   private int die2;
   private int die3;
   private int die4;
   private int die5;
   Random r = new Random();
   List<Integer> dietype1 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10);
   List<Integer> dietype2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10);
   ArrayList<Integer> diesrolled = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   public ArrayList<Integer> rollDice(){
      die1 = (dietype1.get(r.nextInt(dietype1.size())));
      die2 = (dietype1.get(r.nextInt(dietype1.size())));
      die3 = (dietype1.get(r.nextInt(dietype1.size())));
      die4 = (dietype1.get(r.nextInt(dietype1.size())));
      die5 = (dietype2.get(r.nextInt(dietype2.size())));
      diesrolled.add(die1);
      diesrolled.add(die2);
      diesrolled.add(die3);
      diesrolled.add(die4);
      diesrolled.add(die5);
      return diesrolled;
   }
 }
```

Player class:

```
public class inc1_player{
   private int totalScore;

   public int getTotalScore(){
      return totalScore;
   }

   public void setTotalScore(int score){
      totalScore += score;
   }
}
```

Game class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inc1{
   private inc1_player player;
   private inc1_dice dice;

   public inc1(inc1_dice dice, inc1_player player){
      this.dice = dice;
      this.player = player;
   }

   public void go(){
         System.out.println(dice.rollDice());
         System.out.println("After that roll your updated score is " + player.getTotalScore());
         dice.rollDice().clear();            
   }

   public void addFivesOrTens(){
      int score = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < dice.rollDice().size(); i++) {         
         if (dice.rollDice().get(i) == 5)
            score = score + 5;
            player.setTotalScore(score);              
         if (dice.rollDice().get(i) == 10)
            score = score + 10;
            player.setTotalScore(score);
      }                    
   }

   public boolean checkIfWinner(){
      if (player.getTotalScore() >= 500)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }  
}
```

Main class:

```
public class inc1_main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        inc1 inc = new inc1(new inc1_dice(), new inc1_player());
    inc.go();
}
 }
```

Comment: Can we see your code with the loop?

Comment: Note that if statements without curly braces only apply to the next statement. Therefore, player.setTotalScore(score); can set the score back to zero.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code. You'll see that you're continually creating objects (running out of heap) and never exiting the loop.

Comment: You're continually increasing the size of the diesrolled ArrayList, so that for loop, `for (int i = 0; i < dice.rollDice().size(); i++) {` will *never* end. Again run this through a debugger. Refactor and simplify this code greatly.

Comment: ***AGAIN*** step through the code with a debugger and you'll see for yourself. It's obvious once you do this most basic step.

Comment: The debugger allows you to step through code, one line at a time, and allows you to inspect fields as you do this, and this is what you should do.

Comment: Sorry, but the "non-necessary" code is needed to allow others to be able to run your code. Please leave it as it was.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's not true. You don't need to run anything. My question was how to format the go method. And it turns out what I had was basically correct. The issue was with the fivesortens method. With all do respect please let me edit my own questions

Comment: I'm afraid it is. Both Miljen and I found your bug by running your runnable code through a debugger. Your question will have much greater relevance to others if you leave the code as is. Please don't deface the question after it has been answered.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Look. We obviously disagree here and will go back and fourth about this. At the end of the day it's my question and I would be happy if you could just move on.

Comment: And on that you're also wrong. Once you've asked the question it becomes property of the site (please read the site's rules on this). We could get a moderator involved, and this is what will happen if you keep defacing the question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay fine. I'm gonna just EDIT the question and try to dumb down and simplify some things. Would that be okay with you?

Comment: Please just leave it as it is. That is the best solution.

Comment: I have notified the moderators, and they will likely lock the question soon.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels There are some unnecessary things in here though. For example, nobody needs to see the main it is completely irrelevant to the question and doesn't have anything at all to do with the answer. I believe that we can at least both agree on that?

Comment: Why is this so important to you? Again, if you leave it as is, the code is runnable by anyone who might come along with a similar problem. Again, why not simply leave the question be? And regarding site policy and question ownership, here's the related meta question link that you will want to read: [OP accepts answer, then vandalizes the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336993/op-accepts-answer-then-vandalizes-the-question/)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's not really important. I understand what you're saying and I'll just let it be. Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you, and the best to you too.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in this part of code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dice.rollDice().size(); i++) {         
     if (dice.rollDice().get(i) == 5)
        score = score + 5;
        player.setTotalScore(score);              
     if (dice.rollDice().get(i) == 10)
        score = score + 10;
        player.setTotalScore(score);
  }
```

You should call `dice.rollDice()` only once and store its result in a variable. The way you wrote, `ArrayList<Integer> diesrolled` keeps growing and your `for` loop never ends because you call `dice.rollDice()` in every iteration of `for` loop and condition `i = dice.rollDice().size()` is never met because `size()` grows faster than `i` - until you finally get `OutOfMemoryException`.

Solution:

- move `ArrayList<Integer> diesrolled = new ArrayList<Integer>();` to `rollDice()` method
- rewrite `addFivesOrTens()` method as:

  ```
  public void addFivesOrTens() {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = dice.rollDice();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {         
       if (a.get(i) == 5)
          player.setTotalScore(5);              
       else if (a.get(i) == 10)
          player.setTotalScore(10);
    }                    
  }
  ```
- rewrite `go()` method as:

  ```
  while (!checkIfWinner()) {
      dice.addFivesOrTens();
  }
  ```

Comment: We're cheating the original poster of learning the skill of using a debugger.

Comment: So something like       a = dice.rollDice(); and then if a.get(i) == 5?

Comment: @destinycoots Exactly, and more important, `for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)`, so put `a = dice.rollDice();` before the loop.

Comment: @MiljenMikic It says that it can't find the a symbol.

Comment: @DestinyCoots `ArrayList<Integer> a = dice.rollDice();`

Comment: @MiljenMikic Okay so no more compiler errors. But I still need to properly format the go method. Beacause what I have now the user rolls 3,10,4,10,4 which should say the score is 20 but it says the score is 120..

Comment: So when the code's behavior doesn't match your expectations, you should use a .... (hint: it starts with "de" and ends with "r")

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I told you in the comments what It said when I ran the debugger on jgrasp. To be honest I don't really know what any of the even means

Comment: @DestinyCoots You should decide whether `player.setTotalScore(score);` *sets* or *adds* points. Currently it adds, and you keep adding also in score variable, so points keep getting added multiple times.

Comment: @MiljenMikic It should be adding that score to the total score. I'm a little confused on your wording. How do points keep getting added multiple times?

Comment: @DestinyCoots Let's say you roll 3,10,4,10,4. Variable `score` is initially zero in `addFivesOrTens` method. When you encounter 10, `score` becomes 10, and you call `player.setTotalScore(10)` which increases total player points by 10. When you again encounter 10, `score` becomes 10 + 10 = 20, and you call `player.setTotalScore(20)` which increases total player points by 20, so in total you increased player points by 10+20 = 30, instead of 20.

Comment: @MiljenMikic Okay so it saves the previous number along with it so the first 10 would be 10 then the second 10 would be worth 20 and the third be worth 30 ect. when it shouldn't.

Comment: @MiljenMikic would possibly having a different variable for scores of 5 and 10 help? I'm just throwing out ideas because I'm not exactly sure how to fix the issue

Comment: @MiljenMikic: I've just checked the OP's posting history, and I suggest that you do the same, and then please have a look at [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). All parts of his assignment are being done on this site -- Please don't do his homework for him.

Comment: @MiljenMikic dice is connected to inc1_dice class so when you do dice.addFivesOrTens it says symbol not found because it isn't in that class

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, I am getting pretty tired at the moment. Didn't check his history so far.

Comment: @MiljenMikic: you've done enough for her already 1+ to your answer. Let her figure out the rest.

Comment: @DestinyCoots: a thousand apologies, ma'am.

Comment: @DestinyCoots Both go() and addFivesOrTens() are in the same class, so you are allowed to call dice.addFivesOrTens() inside go() method. I believe I helped you enough, it is pretty late in my timezone so I wish you best of luck. If you apply my answer, your code should work.